# How to publish to PubSub using personal (gcloud) credentials

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish a message to GCP PubSub using the same credentials that the `gcloud` CLI does but not having a lot of success.

I can confirm that I can post to a topic by doing

`gcloud pubsub topics publish myTopic --project "myProject" --message "Hello World!"`

However when I try using the exact same credentials as gcloud using the code below

```golang
creds, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to retrieve default credentials: %v", err))
}
client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, "myproject", option.WithCredentials(creds))
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("unable to create GCP storage client: %v", err))
}
topic := client.Topic("myTopic")
r := topic.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
    Data: []byte("Hello World!"),
})
_, err = r.Get(ctx)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to publish message: %v", err))
}
```

I get the following error message

```
panic: failed to publish message: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have also tried loading the json file directly to make sure it is not picking up some other default credentials somewhere but got the same error.

How can I use the same credentials as the gcloud CLI to publish to a pubsub topic I have permissions to?

Comment: What is your credential loaded into the CLI? How did you do this?

Comment: It's been a while since I needed to login into gcloud but I believe it was using the south flow where gcloud opens a web browser and I login in the browser and it then stores a token locally. Since then I never need to login into gcloud

Comment: Ok, got it. I post an answer, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Did you to try the option impersonate-service-account? [1]
Perhaps this is what you are looking for. Hoping it helps...

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--impersonate-service-account

Answer (score 0):

When I configure my local environment, I'm doing this

- Run the command: `gcloud auth application-default login`
- Click on the link and allo Google Auth Library

The result of the command should display something like this

```
Credentials saved to file: [/path/to/application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC).
```

- Copy the `/path/to/application_default_credentials.json`
- Create the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with this value. In linux: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/application_default_credentials.json`

Now, your personal credentials are also defined as the default credentials for your apps running on your local environment.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) in your Go script. By default, it will use the same credentials as the ones present in the environment where you run your code.

This is an example for setting up a new client with default credentials when creating a bucket:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage" 


func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Sets your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
    projectID := "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"

    // Creates a client.
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
```

Accordingly, try this in your code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
client := pubsub.NewClient(ctx)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Your code just creates a new storage client. I am doing the same except I am creating a PubSub client. The authentication part described in your link talks about creating a service account which is not what I want to do. Clearly it is possible to use my own credentials as gcloud does it without me having to create a service account. Maybe I missunderstood what you meant?

Comment: I modified my answer to be more specific. Hope it helps!